# Import variable values from an external JS file

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file located in directory c:\myJSfiles\FileNumberOne.xyz

```
    //c:\myJSfiles\FileNumberone.xyz 

    var 1 = ThisValue1;
    var 2 - ThisValue2;
    and so on
```

In the same root directory, I have second JS file c:\myJSfiles\FileNumberTwo.xyz which I want to import the values of the variables from FileNumberOne.xyz

```
    //file: c:\myJSfiles\FileNumberTwo.xyz

    var A = "c:\myJSfiles\FileNumberOne.xyz", var 1;
    var B = "c:\myJSfiles\FileNumberOne.xyz", var 2;
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Would be great if you can share the exact extension of the file instead of saying "xyz" .

Answer (score 1):

`var 1` makes no sense, I assume you did it as an example only. Otherwise if you declare something in the first referenced script on the page, it will automatically be available in the second.

for example if you have in

```
<script src="Script1.js"></script>
```

line

```
var something = "hello"
```

you can reference the second script after the first

```
<script src="Script2.js"></script>
```

and in that script use that variable

```
alert(something); // will display hello
```

Comment: Since I am a beginner, I am confused about applying your answer to my situation. var1 = ThisValue1 which is a number that changes frequently as is var 2. Would you be so kind as to write your answer so I can see how ThisValue1 makes it into the second JS file...Thanks

Comment: Please note, this JS is not a webpage.

Comment: @ddawson7 were do you run your JS then - what environment?

Comment: Within a charting application

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What is the application name, what technologies does it use? Windows, Web, etc.?